# How to remove accent from string in WP7

Tags: string, windows-phone-7, diacritics, normalize, non-ascii-characters

I want to remove accent (diacritic) from string in Windows Phone 7.
The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net) works for .NET (desktop version). However, WP7 string has no `Normalize` method.

[Someone suggest change from string to byte](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/e274873c-622d-423b-ba74-74b1fd491a78/), but I dont know what he means. How to remove accent ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this:

```cs
public static string RemoveAccents(this string accentedStr)
{
    byte[] tempBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-8").GetBytes(accentedStr);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tempBytes, 0, tempBytes.Length);
}
```

Edit: this solution works in Windows 8 apps, but not in Windows Phone. The best solution I have found so far is this manual one:
http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/how-to-remove-diatrics-accent-marks-in-windows-phone-7-x/

Comment: I've already seen it on codeproject, but in WP7 I receive **ISO-8859-8' is not a supported encoding name**

Comment: I have to accept the manual solution from link. =[
But it worked very well.